# Is there a name for this Fibonacci Identity

Tags: number-theory, fibonacci-numbers

Last night I was trying to solve a problem and discovered an identity relating to the Fibonacci sequence

$$ \left\lvert F_{i-j}F_{i+j} - F_{i-k}F_{i+k} \right\lvert = \left\lvert F_{k - j}F_{k+j} \right\lvert $$

Where $F_{n}$ is the $n$th term of the Fibonacci sequence. The modulus brackets remove the awkwardness of the $(-1)$ exponent, which gives

$$ F_{i-j}F_{i+j} - F_{i-k}F_{i+k} = F_{k-j}F_{j+k} (-1)^{(i + k)} $$

When $j=1$ and $k=0$ we get the Cassini identity, but is there a name for this more generalized form?

Comment: Possibly looks like Vajda's extension of Cassini?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[Vajda's identity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cassini_and_Catalan_identities#References) states that (I have changed subscript variables to reassign then to derive your equality):
$$
\left|F_{r+s}F_{r+t}-F_rF_{r+s+t}\right|=\left|F_sF_t\right|.
$$

The above identity can be derived from this by setting $r=i-k$, $s=k+j$, and $t=k-j$.

Comment: I figured it was a derivation of Vajda; mine looks more elegant though don't you think? :)

Answer (score 2):

This is equivalent to an identity of Alberto Tagiuri: equation (3) in 
*[Di alcune successioni ricorrenti a termini interi e positivi](https://archive.org/details/periodicodimate08mathgoog/page/n12)*, Periodico di Matematica 16 (1900–1901), 1–12.

Answer (score 0):

Your Fibonacci identity

> $$ F_{i-j}F_{i+j} - F_{i-k}F_{i+k} = F_{k-j}F_{j+k} (-1)^{(i + k)} $$

is derived from the identity

$$ 0 = (a-b)(a+b) -(a-c)(a+c) +(b-c)(b+c) $$

with label $\texttt{id3_3_1_2b}$  in my collection of
[Special Algebraic Identities](https://grail.eecs.csuohio.edu/%7Esomos/ident04.gp).

It is equivalent to, but more symmetrical than Vajda's identity which is
derived from

$$ 0 = (a-b)(a-c) -bc -a(a-b-c) $$

with label $\texttt{id3_3_1_2c}$.

The answer to your question

> ... but is there a name for this more generalized form?

is probably no. There are very few named identities, especially for Fibonacci
numbers. Anyone can propose a name, but it has to gain acceptance.